# ggplot color by factor levels, some color are very similar, unable to distinguish points for some groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used the following code to get the graph. The problem of this graph is the colors of d=330421, d=330500 and d=330623 are very similar, it is hard to distinguish which point belongs to which group.

```
ggplot(subdt2, aes(x=year, y=aniHusb, color = d)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: The ColorBrewer palettes might be better for large numbers of categories, e.g. `scale_colour_brewer(type = "qual")`. Otherwise packages like `ggthemes` have a variety of colour palettes you could try.

Comment: May be use  `shape` as well.

Comment: Generally, distinguishing *10* colours and readily identifying them (in e.g. a legend) is difficult for most. *6* is doable, perhaps 7-8. You would need to break it into series or use other factors for distinguishing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this to generate the plot with distinguishable colors:

```
library(randomcoloR)
n <- length(unique(subdt2$d))
palette <- unname(distinctColorPalette(n))
ggplot(subdt2, aes(x=year, y=aniHusb, color = d)) + 
   geom_point() + scale_color_manual(values=palette)
```

or Using `RColorBrewer` package:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
ggplot(subdt2, aes(x=year, y=aniHusb, color = d)) + 
   geom_point() + scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set3")
```

Example:

```
ggplot(iris[iris$Species=='setosa',], aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color = as.factor(Petal.Length))) + 
    geom_point() + scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set3")
```

Plot:

[image]

```
n <- length(unique(iris[iris$Species=='setosa','Petal.Length']))
palette <- unname(distinctColorPalette(n))

ggplot(iris[iris$Species=='setosa',], aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color = as.factor(Petal.Length))) + 
    geom_point() + scale_color_manual(values=palette)
```

[image]